# Why would SQL Server's SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH not be honored?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, deadlock

I've captured a SQL Server 2012 deadlock graph (using [Gail Shaw's](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/sql-server-deadlocks-by-example/) query) that shows a process with taskpriority="10" being picked as the deadlock victim over 2 processes with taskpriority="0".

My understanding is that the deadlock priority is checked first and lower priority processes will be chosen as the victim. Only when all processes are equal priority will other factors be relevant. Can anyone shed any light on why DEADLOCK_PRIORITY might not be honored?

Interestingly, the [SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-deadlock-priority-transact-sql) MSDN page says that HIGH maps to 5, and my code definitely uses HIGH, so I'm not sure where the 10 comes from.

Annoyingly, the victim is an important business process whilst the survivors are both SSMS Intellisense queries.

**Edit**

Firstly, this question is about why DEADLOCK_PRIORITY would not be honoured, not what deadlocks are or how to prevent them or work around them or what caused the one in the example below. Those are all interesting conversations, but not here.

Secondly, a couple of additional facts that might be relevant based on links found by @SteveFord; Lock partitioning is enabled on this SQL Server and the SQL Server version is earlier than 2012 CU6 (when the patch in KB2776344 was released.

Thirdly, for those interested here is a sanitised deadlock graph, showing the higher priority process being chosen as the victim. I've removed SQL and changed a few names, everything else is intact.

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process5f390c8" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process5f390c8" taskpriority="10" logused="3200" waitresource="KEY: 6:281474978938880 (655334c51469)" waittime="1806" ownerId="296690694" transactionname="ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION" lasttranstarted="2018-01-29T11:59:36.140" XDES="0x886312d28" lockMode="X" schedulerid="9" kpid="32684" status="suspended" spid="86" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="5" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-29T11:58:38.310" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-29T11:58:38.310" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.310" clientapp="CLIENTAPP" hostname="HOSTNAME" hostpid="10912" loginname="DOMAIN\USERNAME" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="296690694" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673187936" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="138" sqlhandle="0x01000600a1f28605207939860500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
...removed...</frame>
        <frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_executesql" line="1" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x0400ff7f427f99d9010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
...removed...</frame>
        <frame procname="SUBSPNAME" line="75" stmtstart="5434" stmtend="5502" sqlhandle="0x0300060011b27f3d08e76c012ba8000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
...removed...</frame>
        <frame procname="SPNAME" line="65" stmtstart="4234" stmtend="4516" sqlhandle="0x030006004990de353efaf70071a8000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
...removed...</frame>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x01000600679e2e28907739860500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
...removed...</frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
...removed...</inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process791872558" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 6:139251651:11 " waittime="8299" ownerId="300839454" transactionname="MDView" lasttranstarted="2018-01-29T12:19:33.727" XDES="0x4cddd58a0" lockMode="Sch-S" schedulerid="9" kpid="20372" status="suspended" spid="75" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-29T12:19:33.720" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-29T12:19:33.713" lastattention="2018-01-29T12:19:18.360" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" hostname="ANOTHERHOSTNAME" hostpid="62236" loginname="DOMAIN\ANOTHERUSERNAME" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="300839326" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="10000" clientoption1="671090784" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="56" sqlhandle="0x02000000c7bca00d097183e2d5dd8e6785f452180936fd930000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
...removed...</frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
...removed...</frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
...removed...</inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="281474978938880" dbid="6" objectname="DBNAME.sys.sysschobjs" indexname="clst" id="lock1ef508c700" mode="U" associatedObjectId="281474978938880">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process791872558" mode="S" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process5f390c8" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <objectlock lockPartition="11" objid="139251651" subresource="FULL" dbid="6" objectname="TABLENAME" id="lock398e43e00" mode="Sch-M" associatedObjectId="139251651">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process5f390c8" mode="Sch-M" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process791872558" mode="Sch-S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </objectlock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the deadlock graph

Comment: @SteveFord The question is about why DEADLOCK_PRIORITY might not be honoured rather than why any specific deadlocks occurred. I was hoping for someone who had observed this behaviour before or had better knowledge of the internal workings of DEADLOCK_PRIORITY than me. I'm posting from work and couldn't easily post the graphs without a lot of sanitising anyway.

Comment: There are some descriptions of possible reasons in this post: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1662375-391-1.aspx. The other thing to consider is whether you are facing a timeout rather than a deadlock victim. SSMS by default runs with no lock timeout but this can be configured.

Comment: What does the graph look like? In particular, is your query deadlocking with multiple other queries at the same time? This is speculation, but based on the fact that the deadlock event always speaks of "*the* deadlock victim", it may be the case that the algorithm prefers to find one single victim to resolve the deadlock, even if the victim has more priority than the other participants, if the only alternative would be killing more than one process. (Verifying this by setting up a deadlock situation should be possible, if a bit tedious.)

Comment: If you haven't already, it's worth setting up a permanent event notification to capture all deadlock events in a table (see [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/handling-deadlocks-in-sql-server/), for example). This makes investigating deadlocks after the fact a lot more convenient (and also allows you to find patterns, and prioritize).

Comment: @SteveFord I'd Googled too and found a few (but not many) similar stories, all of them light on hard facts. Your link does include a couple of very interesting links from Jacob Wilkins though. I can confirm that Lock partitioning is enabled on this server and the SQL Server version is earlier than 2012 CU6 (when the patch in KB2776344 was released).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've already Googled and found speculation about this - it's hard facts I'm after. I hear what you're saying, but it doesn't reflect the expected, documented, behaviour for DEADLOCK_PRIORITY.

Comment: The documented behavior for `DEADLOCK_PRIORITY` actually fails to say anything meaningful about the case where *more than two* sessions are involved in the deadlock. Or rather, what it says simply can't be reconciled with that situation. If I have time to spare, I'll see about setting up a reproducible three-way deadlock. My suggestion for a permanent trace was because this allows you to establish quite simply, with a query, if your high priority query always wins when it is in competition with only one lower-priority session, but never with more. That would be as hard a fact as you can get.

Comment: @JeroenMostert My interpretation of the docs for DEADLOCK_PRIORITY is that it applies regardless of the number of processes. I have a graph from this morning showing a high priority process being chosen as the victim with only 1 other process in the deadlock. The permanent trace would be useful but isn't a simple thing to implement in my corporate workplace.

Comment: Well, if you have an actual example of a higher-priority process being chosen as the deadlock victim in a deadlock involving only one other, lower priority process, then obviously I won't waste time on the three-way case. :-) (Actually posting the deadlock graph so people have something to chew on is still a good idea; you can sanitize the identifiers of columns/tables/databases involved `Foo`/`Bar`/`Baz` style without the graph losing its explanatory value, as long as different objects are still different.)

Comment: Aside. If `DEADLOCK_PRIORITY` won't help you there are at least three other fruitful avenues of things to try: increase the locking of your important business process so it won't get into a deadlock situation in the first place (by using locking hints on initial `SELECT` queries and putting everything in a transaction, for example), eliminate the lower-priority queries altogether by setting up mirrors or snapshots (so nobody has a need to perform "SMSS Intellisense queries" on a critical server), eliminate read locks by snapshot isolation. None of this answers the question proper, of course.

Comment: It looks like the command which is being killed is an ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION, it is interesting to note that this requires a SCH-M lock which is incompatible with  SCH-S locks which are taken for everything. I guess this may be a cause. See http://michaeljswart.com/2013/04/the-sch-m-lock-is-evil/. Also see this description of a SCH-M deadlock from an ALTER PARTITION Function and a query that causes a statistics update in SQL 2014 & 2016, but maybe true in 2012 too: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3174476/fix-deadlock-occurs-when-you-acquire-a-sch-m-lock-and-alter-a-partitio

Comment: So one process has a shared (update) lock on sysschobjs and is waiting for a SCHM-S lock on your table. Your process has a SCH-M lock on your table and is waiting for a X lock on sysschobjs. sysschobjs is a system base table which sits behind sysobjects. See the discussion here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/741a7463-b755-49ed-bbd9-70b7379033f1/sql-query-that-causes-deadlock-often?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: @RhysJones posted comments as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the command which is being killed is an ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION, it is interesting to note that this requires a SCH-M lock which is incompatible with SCH-S locks which are taken for everything. I guess this may be a cause.

See [michaeljswart.com/2013/04/the-sch-m-lock-is-evil](http://michaeljswart.com/2013/04/the-sch-m-lock-is-evil/).

Also see this description of a SCH-M deadlock from an ALTER PARTITION Function and a query that causes a statistics update in SQL 2014 & 2016, but maybe true in 2012 too: [Deadlock Occurs when you acquire a SCH-M lock](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3174476/fix-deadlock-occurs-when-you-acquire-a-sch-m-lock-and-alter-a-partitio)

Looking at your graph, one process has a shared (update) lock on sysschobjs and is waiting for a SCH-S lock on your table. Your process has a SCH-M lock on your table and is waiting for a X lock on sysschobjs. sysschobjs is a system base table which sits behind sysobjects. See the discussion here [Technet: SQL Query that causes deadlock often](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/741a7463-b755-49ed-bbd9-70b7379033f1/sql-query-that-causes-deadlock-often?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Hope this helps

> Update
>   If you want to research this further I have found the MS Patent description of how the Deadlock Monitor chooses victims [here](https://www.google.tl/patents/US9104989)