# Setting deadlock_priority does not make LOW priority session the victim

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking, deadlock

One of our jobs was deadlocking with user routines, so we put the following code in the job step, just before the procedure is called:

```
DECLARE @deadlock_var NCHAR(3);  
SET @deadlock_var = N'LOW';  
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY @deadlock_var;
*--Call procedure
exec Client_myDeliveries_I_S*
```

However, the procedure is still in the stack that is processed.
**Does the deadlock priority not get inherited through the chain of sub procedures?**
I can confirm that at no point does the deadlock victim session set its deadlock_priority.

The complete deadlock XML is below, with some deletions for privacy:

```
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process28fc21868" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process28fc21868" taskpriority="0" logused="2504" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594562412544 (40fd182c0dd9)" waittime="5008" ownerId="299034576" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2018-02-01T12:22:55.580" XDES="0x140b2cc70" lockMode="X" schedulerid="1" kpid="3600" status="suspended" spid="87" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-02-01T12:22:55.580" lastbatchcompleted="2018-02-01T12:22:55.580" lastattention="2018-02-01T12:22:52.480" clientapp="EUROSTOP e-i Service" hostname="SRVAZBRWSQL01" hostpid="1328" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="299034576" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="ALL.dbo.trgi_u_Constants" line="705" stmtstart="37030" stmtend="37270" sqlhandle="0x03000500651fce5aad8fd3002aa5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
update myconstants
                set value = (select last_c_no from inserted)
                where batch = 'last_c_no'    </frame>
    <frame procname="IF_TEST.myschema.SendTestData_Customers_SToALL_Customers" line="87" stmtstart="11420" stmtend="11650" sqlhandle="0x030007007f19ab663ac3e5005ca7000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
update myschema.ALL_Constants
            set     last_c_no = @nLastCNumber + @NumberOfInsertedCs    </frame>
    <frame procname="IF_TEST.myschema.SendTestData_Customers" line="22" stmtstart="962" stmtend="1196" sqlhandle="0x030007009c954b7757b4d00054a7000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
exec myschema.SendTestData_Customers_SToALL_Customers @MessageCode, @RejectAllOnValidationError    </frame>
    <frame procname="IF_TEST.myschema.SendSubmittedFData" line="13" stmtstart="876" stmtend="1114" sqlhandle="0x030007009b4fb66e2db4d00054a7000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
exec [myschema].[SendTestData_Customers] @MessageCode, @RejectAllOnValidationError

    -- Customer Orders    </frame>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="104" sqlhandle="0x010007008547740e50dc4dd90700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
Exec myschema.SendSubmittedFData @0, @1, @2, @3    </frame>
    <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@0 nvarchar(4000),@1 int,@2 nvarchar(4000),@3 int);Exec myschema.SendSubmittedFData @0, @1, @2, @3   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process2b6e94cf8" taskpriority="-6" logused="43652" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594562412544 (d08358b1108f)" waittime="5009" ownerId="299033786" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2018-02-01T12:22:53.810" XDES="0x28262f130" lockMode="X" schedulerid="2" kpid="13408" status="suspended" spid="122" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="-5" trancount="3" lastbatchstarted="2018-02-01T12:15:00.580" lastbatchcompleted="2018-02-01T12:15:00.580" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.580" clientapp="SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0x24121E41ABD80643985B522FE6C248A7 : Step 1)" hostname="SRVAZBRWSQL01" hostpid="2252" loginname="SRVAZBRWSQL01\ALLSYSTEM" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="299033786" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="ALL.dbo.trgi_u_Constants" line="726" stmtstart="38142" stmtend="38386" sqlhandle="0x03000500651fce5aad8fd3002aa5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
update myconstants
                set value = (select last_gs_rec_no from inserted)
                where batch = 'last_gs_rec_no'    </frame>
    <frame procname="ALL.dbo.trgi_i_i_I_deliveries" line="1005" stmtstart="69046" stmtend="69220" sqlhandle="0x030005006cd104389a850d00a1a6000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
update dbo.Constants set last_gs_rec_no = last_gs_rec_no + @nmyDeliveriesCreatedCount    </frame>
    <frame procname="C_HELP.dbo.Client_myDeliveries_I_Std" line="86" stmtstart="7306" stmtend="8324" sqlhandle="0x030006000d09a1438efcba0074a8000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
insert  into [ALL].dbo.i_I_deliveries
                --[columns]
                select  --[columns]
                from    #Client_deliveries_PO_stg stg    </frame>
    <frame procname="C_HELP.dbo.Client_myDeliveries_I_S" line="446" stmtstart="32832" stmtend="33032" sqlhandle="0x0300060028323b37f7a70101eca7000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
exec  dbo.Client_myDeliveries_I_Std @week_selector, @username, @factory_bin_location, @Parameter    </frame>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="6" stmtstart="216" sqlhandle="0x02000000e49e3111676b7e3aec714d06946692f70e3a8a880000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
exec Client_myDeliveries_I_S    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
DECLARE @deadlock_var NCHAR(3);  
SET @deadlock_var = N'LOW';  

SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY @deadlock_var;

exec Client_myDeliveries_I_S   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <keylock hobtid="72057594562412544" dbid="5" objectname="ALL.dbo.myconstants" indexname="pk_myconstants" id="lockd5ad7b00" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72057594562412544">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process2b6e94cf8" mode="RangeS-S" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process28fc21868" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
  <keylock hobtid="72057594562412544" dbid="5" objectname="ALL.dbo.myconstants" indexname="pk_myconstants" id="lock9466df00" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72057594562412544">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process28fc21868" mode="RangeS-S" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process2b6e94cf8" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

**Additional**
Version:
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU2) (KB3137746) - 11.0.6523.0 (X64) 
    Mar  2 2016 21:29:16 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Looking at the XML, it looks like the victim does indeed have a lower priority than the survivor. I admit that that has me stumped!

Comment: Does the low priority job call or trigger the victim in any way?

Comment: No. They are completely unrelated processes.

Comment: What happens if you do SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY -10; ?

Comment: Similar issues to this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381299/why-would-sql-servers-set-deadlock-priority-high-not-be-honored/48631251#48631251 . The only thing I note is that the lower priority process started 2 seconds before the deadlock victim. I think SQL Server also takes into account the amount of work done when choosing deadlock victims and your victim appears to have done no updates a that time.

Comment: In fact if you look at the logused for each you will see the victim has used 2,504 and the lower priority task has used 43,652. So significantly less log space to roll back for the victim.

Comment: According to the documentation, that shouldn't matter, since the log space is only considered if the priority is identical. If that's really the cause here, it's a bug in SQL Server, not a programming error.

Comment: @GregViers I'll try -10 and report back.

Comment: @GregViers Same problem but the successful spid is showing taskpriority -6, not -10; the victim still on 0. I've seen other similar threads but no conclusive reason.

Comment: Is there a lot of Updates/inserts into ALL.dbo.myconstants ? Or is it just constants that don't change?

Comment: @GregViers MyConstants is a single row table with 100+ columns that are updated and locked while larger processes occur, using the frequently incremented values. Should be called MyVariables! If the process fails, the column is not updated with an incremented value. All columns are locked during each process that requiring a value. It is a central unique number distributer to client machines. Bad design but nothing can be done about that. This is one example of deadlocking. We have others with similar priority anomalies, which is what I need to address.

Comment: Can it be redesigned as a single column table with 100+ rows?

Comment: @GregViers We are stuck with this for the time being. It deadlocks on other tables also, so it is just the priority setting I am looking to pin down.

Comment: @cloudsafe depending upon the version of SQL Server you might want to look at using SEQUENCES as a central unique number generator.

Comment: I've found this article about creating a multi-victim deadlock and noticed that both victims had a higher task priority than the process that survived. It also mentions the developer who wrote the deadlock monitor.https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/changes-to-the-deadlock-monitor-for-the-extended-events-xml_deadlock_report-and-multi-victim-deadlocks/

Comment: The Microsoft Patent for Deadlock monitoring only states that "the resolution system should typically not abort a higher priority task". https://www.google.tl/patents/US9104989

Comment: It seems that deadlock priority is being ignored for the majority of deadlocks on our system. As I understand it, this is likely due to algorithms that are not understood or documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From everyone's input, it seems that deadlock priority can be ignored by SQL Server under circumstances that have not been made clear by Microsoft (that we know of); the algorithms used to determine the victim are not understood or documented. If anyone can find solid information on this topic, please share.